# How to silence logs in Java Image Builder (jib)

Tags: gradle, jib

Using JIB in CI produces a mountain of logs because it prints progress, is there a simple way to turn them off?

In my case I am using the Gradle plugin, but I suspect it is the same issue with the Maven plugin

Comment: -q option will run the gradle in quit mode example `./gradlew -q build`

Comment: that silences all logs, i was wondering if i could remove just jib logs

Comment: looks like jib plugin provides a set of properties.. should be possible to achieve by tweaking one of them. Example - https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#:~:text=between%20multiple%20images.-,jib.console,-String

Comment: @Vencat if you put that as an answer I'll accept it. you could also use this link, which is a bit more reliable i think - https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/5e787b580ddd59e419b87330f8e370692f8c22b2/jib-gradle-plugin/README.md?plain=1#L320

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't feel to put it as an answer since what I said in the comment is just a suggestion. If you have any small working examples or more info regarding this thread please post your own answer as it'll help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use the property `jib.console` as described in https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin. Simply set

```
-Djib.console=plain
```

That should make all the verbose output during the image build disappear.